# Report on patch compliance status for Azure VMs with Update Management via Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, report, patch, azure-rm

I'm using Azure Update Management to patch my machines, and can easily view a list of my VMs and their compliance status in one of the columns, any idea how I can pull this same information using Powershell with either AzureRM or Az CLI?

Thanks

Comment: If you have no idea how to do something, it's not going to be a suitable question on stackoverflow. We are here to help you with your code when you are stuck, and as it stands you aren't stuck because you haven't tried anything.

Comment: ok so what I'm looking for is a property of either AzAutomationUpdateManagement or just an AzureRMVM that has this information. Sorry I've not mentioned everything I've tried up until this point, I didn't really see it being that relevant because it was fruitless.

Comment: We need your code to help steer you right. Errors too please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the non-compliant virtual machines, you could try [this script](https://chen.about-powershell.com/2019/10/retrieve-non-compliant-virtual-machines-azure-update-management/). This script uses the new `Az` module, if you are using the old `AzureRM` module, change the `Get-AzContext` to `Get-AzureRmContext` like below.

```
param (
    $SUBSCRIPTIONID,

    $AUTOMATIONACCOUNTNAME,

    $RESOURCEGROUPNAME,

    $WORKSPACE
)
#region - Generate a bearer token
$azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext
$profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId)
#endregion


$Query = @"
{
    "top": 1000000000,
    "query": "Heartbeat\n| where TimeGenerated>ago(12h) and OSType==\"Linux\" and notempty(Computer) | where ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\"\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, Solutions, Computer, ResourceId, ComputerEnvironment, VMUUID) by SourceComputerId\n| where Solutions has \"updates\" \n| extend vmuuId=VMUUID, azureResourceId=ResourceId, osType=1,\nenvironment=iff(ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\", 1, 2),\nscopedToUpdatesSolution=true, lastUpdateAgentSeenTime=\"\"\n| join kind=leftouter (Update\n| where TimeGenerated>ago(5h) and OSType==\"Linux\" and SourceComputerId in ((Heartbeat\n| where TimeGenerated>ago(12h) and OSType==\"Linux\" and notempty(Computer)\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, Solutions) by SourceComputerId\n| where Solutions has \"updates\" | distinct SourceComputerId)) | where ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\"\n| summarize hint.strategy=partitioned arg_max(TimeGenerated, UpdateState, Classification, Product, Computer, ComputerEnvironment) by SourceComputerId, Product, ProductArch \n| summarize Computer=any(Computer), ComputerEnvironment=any(ComputerEnvironment), missingCriticalUpdatesCount=countif(Classification has \"Critical\" and UpdateState=~\"Needed\"),\nmissingSecurityUpdatesCount=countif(Classification has \"Security\" and UpdateState=~\"Needed\"),\nmissingOtherUpdatesCount=countif(Classification !has \"Critical\" and Classification !has \"Security\" and UpdateState=~\"Needed\"),\nlastAssessedTime=max(TimeGenerated), lastUpdateAgentSeenTime=\"\" by SourceComputerId\n| extend compliance=iff(missingCriticalUpdatesCount > 0 or missingSecurityUpdatesCount > 0, 2, 1)\n| extend ComplianceOrder=iff(missingCriticalUpdatesCount > 0 or missingSecurityUpdatesCount > 0 or missingOtherUpdatesCount > 0, 1, 3)) on SourceComputerId\n| project id=SourceComputerId, displayName=Computer ,sourceComputerId=SourceComputerId, azureResourceId, scopedToUpdatesSolution=true,\nmissingCriticalUpdatesCount=coalesce(missingCriticalUpdatesCount, -1), missingSecurityUpdatesCount=coalesce(missingSecurityUpdatesCount, -1), missingOtherUpdatesCount=coalesce(missingOtherUpdatesCount, -1), compliance=coalesce(compliance, 4), lastAssessedTime, lastUpdateAgentSeenTime, osType=1, environment=iff(ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\", 1, 2), ComplianceOrder=coalesce(ComplianceOrder, 2)\n | where compliance in (2) | union(Heartbeat\n| where TimeGenerated>ago(12h) and OSType=~\"Windows\" and notempty(Computer) | where ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\"\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, Solutions, Computer, ResourceId, ComputerEnvironment, VMUUID) by SourceComputerId\n| where Solutions has \"updates\" \n| extend vmuuId=VMUUID, azureResourceId=ResourceId, osType=2,\nenvironment=iff(ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\", 1, 2),\nscopedToUpdatesSolution=true, lastUpdateAgentSeenTime=\"\"\n| join kind=leftouter (Update\n| where TimeGenerated>ago(14h) and OSType!=\"Linux\" and SourceComputerId in ((Heartbeat\n| where TimeGenerated>ago(12h) and OSType=~\"Windows\" and notempty(Computer)\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, Solutions) by SourceComputerId\n| where Solutions has \"updates\" | distinct SourceComputerId)) | where ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\"\n| summarize hint.strategy=partitioned arg_max(TimeGenerated, UpdateState, Classification, Title, Optional, Approved, Computer, ComputerEnvironment) by Computer, SourceComputerId, UpdateID \n| summarize Computer=any(Computer), ComputerEnvironment=any(ComputerEnvironment), missingCriticalUpdatesCount=countif(Classification has \"Critical\" and UpdateState=~\"Needed\" and Approved!=false),\nmissingSecurityUpdatesCount=countif(Classification has \"Security\" and UpdateState=~\"Needed\" and Approved!=false),\nmissingOtherUpdatesCount=countif(Classification !has \"Critical\" and Classification !has \"Security\" and UpdateState=~\"Needed\" and Optional==false and Approved!=false),\nlastAssessedTime=max(TimeGenerated), lastUpdateAgentSeenTime=\"\" by SourceComputerId\n| extend compliance=iff(missingCriticalUpdatesCount > 0 or missingSecurityUpdatesCount > 0, 2, 1)\n| extend ComplianceOrder=iff(missingCriticalUpdatesCount > 0 or missingSecurityUpdatesCount > 0 or missingOtherUpdatesCount > 0, 1, 3)) on SourceComputerId\n| project id=SourceComputerId, displayName=Computer, sourceComputerId=SourceComputerId, azureResourceId, scopedToUpdatesSolution=true,\nmissingCriticalUpdatesCount=coalesce(missingCriticalUpdatesCount, -1), missingSecurityUpdatesCount=coalesce(missingSecurityUpdatesCount, -1), missingOtherUpdatesCount=coalesce(missingOtherUpdatesCount, -1), compliance=coalesce(compliance, 4), lastAssessedTime, lastUpdateAgentSeenTime, osType=2, environment=iff(ComputerEnvironment=~\"Azure\", 1, 2), ComplianceOrder=coalesce(ComplianceOrder, 2)\n | where compliance in (2)) | order by ComplianceOrder asc, missingCriticalUpdatesCount desc, missingSecurityUpdatesCount desc, missingOtherUpdatesCount desc, displayName asc"
}
"@ 


$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($SUBSCRIPTIONID)/resourcegroups/$($RESOURCEGROUPNAME)/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/$($WORKSPACE)/query?api-version=2017-10-01&q_OrchestratorExtension.DataModels.Computer" -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer {0}" -f ($token.AccessToken)
} -Method Post -Body ($Query) -ContentType 'application/json'

$Collection = @()
$result.tables.rows  | %{
    $Collection += [pscustomobject]@{
        VMName = $_[1]
        CriticalUpdateMissing = $_[5]
        SecurityUpdateMissing = $_[6]

    }
} 
$Collection
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop using AzureRM-Cmdlets. Use the new Az-CMDlets instead.

There is no cmdlet available to get the Patch-Status Out-of-the Box.

You could fetch the Status from the linked Log-Analytics-Account like

```
UpdateSummary 
| where OldestMissingSecurityUpdateInDays != 0
| summarize Computer = dcount(Computer == "Resource") by Resource
```

Or you're using the new Graph-API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-windowsupdatestate-get?view=graph-rest-beta