# Retrieve Update-Management related details for a vm - AZURE

Tags: automation, azure-virtual-machine

In azure API Documentation, AZURE - VM API's not providing an API to retrieve update management related information for the VM [image: Information that are appeared here]

Is there a possible way of retrieving Update Management related details from **azure VM** or from **Automation account**(as a summary for all VMs).

Comment: Have you looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/?

Comment: yes, found only details on update deployments, related VMs but not the results(compliant and non-compliant status) of the VMs. Do I have to read log analytics to get those data?

Comment: Whenever I am not able to find relevant API for a particular feature, one thing that I do is open the feature in Portal and observe the networking tab in the browser. That tells me the REST API Portal is using for a particular feature. You may want to give that a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip.. seems like the API related to the information I need, is not available in the network call. possibly for a security reason.

Answer (score 0):

@Thanuja as you mentioned in the comment section, we don’t have api available to get the results.

You can view the results from log analytics data(work space), or else you can retrieve the information using power shell script as discussed in this
[Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713672/report-on-patch-compliance-status-for-azure-vms-with-update-management-via-power)